Flutter Serverpod Email Validation
Can anyone explain how to send the validation code from serverpod to flutter app via message or email .Instead of printing the validation code  in the terminal
Using Mailgun , Sendgrid or any smtp server to send the validation code to flutter app rather than sending the code via gmail .

This is pretty easy, you just have to call the mail service API you want to use inside the sendValidationEmail callback.
For example if using mailgun you can use a client lib like this: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_mailgun
Then craft an email with the code like so:

import 'package:serverpod_auth_server/module.dart' as auth;
import 'package:dart_mailgun/client.dart';

...

var client = MailgunClient(domain: "my-mailgun-domain", apiKey: "my-mailgun-api-key");

auth.AuthConfig.set(auth.AuthConfig(
  sendValidationEmail: (session, email, validationCode) async {
    
    var messageClient = client.message
    var params = MessageParams(
      from: 'noreply@mydomain.com',
      to: email,
      subject: 'Serverpod code',
      content: MessageContent.html('<h1>$validationCode</h1>'),
    )
    await messageClient.send(params)

    return true;
  },

));

See the auth docs for more configs: https://docs.serverpod.dev/concepts/authentication/providers/email#server-side-configuration
